# C# Winforms change label based on running process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a dotnet 2.0 app in C# that I have developed in Visual Studio 2008, it's pretty simple:

[image]

I would like to change the label name currently called "label1" to "Running" or "Stopped" when my process loop.exe is running or stopped.

When I press start, it will run loop.exe and the stop button will obviously stop it.

I've read a lot of topic on C# Winforms but I cannot get this working and I have no idea what do to now. I think that I need to add a backgroundworker but I don't know how to check the process and update the label programmatically.

Here's my clean/current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace APP_NAME
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("loop.exe");

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM loop.exe");
            Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM azcopy.exe");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\ProgramData\APP_NAME\settings\settings.xml");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\ProgramData\APP_NAME\logs");
        }

    }
}
```

I hope I made myself clear, thank you.

Comment: you can sample ""loop.exe" every X seconds to check its status using [Process.GetProcessesByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Greetings, got two questions for you, first I assume you wanna change the Text of label1 to "Running" or "Stopped", not the name? and second does your loop.exe has some output or return code when its finish?

Comment: Hi styx, i'm check your link, thanks.

Comment: S.Fragkos: Yes exactly, the loop will run forever until it's manually stopped so no return whatsover.

Comment: Process.Start() has a return value, a Process object reference.  You'll like its Exited event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the text shown by a label by accessing it's `Text` property. So, change your method like:

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("loop.exe");
    label1.Text = "Running";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//hi
//Do this to see the label value changes in real time in the window

```
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("loop.exe");
        label1.Text = "Running";
        lable1.Refresh();

    }
```